# Add SET STATEMENT before SELECT in Yii 1.1.16 QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, select, yii

I'm trying to find a way to append...

```
SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1000 FOR
```

...at the start of a Yii QueryBuilder SQL call, eg:

```
$Query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
$Query->select = "*";
$Query->from = "table";
$Query->where = "id = 1";
```

Adding to the `$Query->select` creates broken SQL:

```
$Query->select = "SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1000 FOR " . "*";
...
SELECT SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1000 FOR * // Syntax error
```

And there doesn't appear to be a 'pre-select' or 'before-select' property:

```
$Query->beforeSelect = "SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=1000 FOR";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need any 'pre-select' or 'before-select' property.

I think you simply need to run a query with your SET command just before your SELECT query.

I've testing with `foreign_key_checks` variable and this is the result:

```
// Disable foreign_key_checks
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SET foreign_key_checks = 0")->execute();

// Check that variable is being kept for this request
CVarDumper::dump(Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks'
")->queryRow(), 10, true);

// Enable foreign_key_checks
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SET foreign_key_checks = 1")->execute();

// Variable is ON again
CVarDumper::dump(Yii::app()->db->createCommand("
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks'
")->queryRow(), 10, true);
```

Result on first `SHOW VARIABLES` command:

```
array
(
    'Variable_name' => 'foreign_key_checks'
    'Value' => 'OFF'
)
```

Result on second`SHOW VARIABLES` command:

```
array
(
    'Variable_name' => 'foreign_key_checks'
    'Value' => 'ON'
)
```

So I understand this should work also in your case.

But please first make sure your SQL syntax is valid, please test it from command line or from a MySQL client before using it in Yii.

I think your syntax is wrong but I cannot test it locally because my server version does not have the max_statement_time variable that was added in version 5.7.4.